# TFS link Unit Test Methods to a Task so in Gated Check-in it can be verified

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tfs, alm

i want to link a set of unit test( List of methods in my Unit Test project) to a Task in TFS. 
So when every i check-in my files for that particular task. in Gated Check-In i want to run those specific test cases(test methods) which i have linked.

And i don't want to run all the test cases in my solution for each check-in.

Is there a way for it?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially.  You would have to customise the gated check in workflow and inspect the check in, see if a task (or multiple tasks) were linked to it and then, before calling the unit test runner, change it so that the call only executes the tests you want.

Good luck with that :-)

Comment: thanks for.. it but what I was looking is how to link a task(requirement) to test methods in tfs.. so when I check-in I get the task id in gated build and from there I can make A query to get list of this methods and run those selected methods only..

Comment: Ah. Now I understand. Unfortunately there's no easy way to do that.
You could look at test impact analysis to do something similar to what you might want, but linking changes directly to specific test methods isn't supported.

Comment: I think this can be useful for people looking stuff similar to me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286589.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A better way can be to just use 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact

It worked for me. but i need to customize my requirements.
http://scrumdod.blogspot.in/2011/03/tfs-2010-build-only-run-impacted-tests.html